# EF Foreign Key Not ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, code-first

Is there a way to make EF map a foreign key to something other than the ID of the second table.

For example;

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sys_id { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string company_id { get; set; }
    public string short_desc { get; set; }
}
```

The tables above hold data pulled in from an external source (this bit works fine and well as being able to query the db) and so I do not have control over the keys. The issue I have is that I need to join Ticket.company_id with Company.sys_id rather then Company.id so that I can use Ticket.company.name or Company.ticket.short_desc etc.

Please can someone tell me how I can implement this?

**EDIT:** I have been looking around and have found the InverseProperty attribute being used to map a ForeignKey to something other then the id of the other table.

For example;

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sys_id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("company_id")]
    [ForeignKey("sys_id")] 
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string company_id { get; set; }
    public string short_desc { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

But I get the error "The property 'company_id' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type." when I try to Add-Migration.

Thanks in advance,
Norman

Comment: If you're certain that sys_id is unique then you can maybe tell EF to ignore the id column and treat the sys_id as the table's key. But then if you try to do inserts via EF you'll probably run into trouble since EF will try to treat sys_id as an identity.

Comment: How about if I need to have 2 tables referencing 2 different foreign keys in the same table?

Answer (score 0):

You could just select `sys_id` as the new key and keep the `id` for other purposes, like this:

```
public class Company
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    [Key, StringLength(128)]
    public string sys_id { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string short_desc { get; set; }

    public string company_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("company_id"), StringLength(128)]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Although i do not recommend this.

Comment: I could but this would mean that I could only use sys_id as a ForeignKey in Company. Is there a way to do this but without making sys_id the key?

Comment: sys_id is the primairy key, and no, you can only have one. You could leave your database as it is, and make the join manually with linq. eg: `from t in Tickets from c in Companies where c.sys_id == t.company_id select new{t.id, t.name}` But i still don't recommend this.

Comment: So what WOULD you recommend when I have a key that is like 2860880096955721844248226442604402882?

Comment: make the sys_id the key. and choose the type varchar(38) or better NUMERIC(38,0) in sql server. And use that to make the relations

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had not seen this update. I currently have it set to do a look up for each record and sets Ticket.company_id to the Company.id that matches the original Company.sys_id. This works but is slow. I will give what you suggested a go. Thanks.